# Rails 3 Rspec form_for Deprecation Warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, tdd, rspec

I have a form_for in my application which looks like:

```
<%= form_for :user, @user, :url => { :controller => 'users', :action => 'update' }, :html => { :multipart => true, :method => 'put' } do |f| %>
```

This works fine.  However, when I run my tests with Rspec I always get:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Using form_for(:name, @resource) is deprecated. Please use form_for(@resource, :as => :name) instead.
```

Which seems to go against what is written in the Rails 3 [forms guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html).  Is this just a bug in rspec or is it actually a deprecation?

Comment: Can you post the modified code that _didn't_ work?

Comment: actually after testing some more the problem isn't the code not working (i had a misplaced end parentheses).  i am editing the question as to whether or not the first method is really deprecated as the rails guides I have seen for 3.0 all seem to use that instead

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to do this

```
<%= form_for @user, :html => {:multipart => true} %>
```

Since Rails will know that @user is an existing record, it'll know to do a PUT request to `users_controller#update`.

Comment: thanks for the response. actually because of the routing i have set up this does not work.  in any case i edited the focus of the original question to be a little clearer on what i was asking.

Comment: Ah, ok. It is odd that the Guides specify use of the "deprecated" format. However, the official Rails docs (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) only specify the newer `form_for @user` format. You may look into the `:as` and `:url` parameters.